# How to enable a Jaalee Beacon

Tags: ibeacon

I have had a pack of four jaalee beacon stickers delivered and I'm having a problem getting them 'woken up'.

According to the website, you have to tap the beacons two or three times. I've tried this a few times but still no cigar, I can't detect them using various bluetooth sniffers.

I'm wondering if I'm tapping them too hard, too soft.

Also found a Jalee app which asks me to press a button on the stickers, no button is visible but I pressed for a few seconds and one of the four stickers 'beeped' once... but the app failed to pair with it. I couldn't get the sticker to beep again.

This was a cheap alternative to Estimote stickers I ordered but which never arrived. So far, beacon sticker technology doesn't seem to be 'there'.

Comment: I have no idea about beacons so I'm taking a shot in the dark here, have you tried the "press and hold" on the sticker rather than just press?

Comment: Thanks for the idea,  I did already try that. The problem was that the press and hold was shown in the instructions I found as in the 'bottom right' of the device, but you actually have to press and hold it firmly in the centre. Also until its been paired with the Jaalee app, it's not enabled. The problem I had was finding correct instructions for how to get it to work. All fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The beacon stickers I have need a few things to happen to be enabled.

1) Download the Jaalee app, I'm not sure it was available when my stickers first arrived. This is the correct app for iPhone for the kind of stickers I have.

[App store link for Jaalee thinnest smart tracker... app](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/jaalee-thinnest-smart-tracker/id751225894?mt=8)

2) Open the app and select a kind of activity to which the beacon is to be enabled (they are trying to ape Estimote I believe). I chose the magnifying glass.

3) On the following dialog select + to add a new sticker.

4) Squeeze the beacon sticker firmly in the centre for several seconds until it beeps.

5) Hold it close enough to the phone/mobile device running the app to enable the app to pair with the beacon and enable it.

At this point the Jaalee beacon should be detectable with a standard Bluetooth sniffer app such as 'LightBlue'

Answer (score 0):

Firmly tap the beacon on a table and it should beep. You may need to turn it over a tap the other side. They need a firm tap.

Once woken up it will be available to connect to and reconfigure. If left it will go back to sleep after about a minute.